# How can I make uniform GUI structure in qml?

Tags: user-interface, qml

I have a few application with the same structure: same topBar, same bottomBar same size of window, and other. How can I create some template or something else to exclude a lot of copy-paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion will be creating a module with your common qml files

check:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

1. Create different qml files like this -

TopBar.qml

```
Item
{
   // Something Something
}
```

BottomBar.qml

```
Item
{
   // Something Something
}
```

AppWindow.qml

```
Item
{
   // Something Something
}
```

Then, whenever you have to use these :

File1.qml

```
Item
{
   // Something Something
   Bottombar
   {} 
}
```

File2.qml

```
Item
{
   // Something Something
   Bottombar
   { x: 0, y: 600} 

   Topbar
   { x: 0, y: 0}

   AppWindow
   { x: 10 ; y : 50 }    
}
```

If you see the analogy, it is something like you created a class and then making objects of this class.